# R select from data frame: by date with repeated factors

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame of addresses and dates of sale. There are multiple entries of some addresses. I want a new data frame that has each address only once and for that address to be selected by the most recent date. Here is a snippet of the data frame.

```
df <-structure(list(address = c("2", "316", "647", "6904", "# 5 BENT TREE DR", "# 62 62000 E 440 PL", "# 7 BENT TREE DR", "#1 ARROWHEAD RD", "#1 ECHO DR", "#1 JACKS HIDEAWAY", "#1 JACKS HIDEAWAY", "#1 MARINA DR", "#1 WHITE CHAPEL", "#10 JACKS HIDEAWAY", "#10 PRIVATEER", "#10 SUMMERSIDE", "#102 THE MOORS", "#103 MOORS VIEW", "#108 THE MOORS", "#111 THE MOORS", "#112 THE MOORS", "#116 THE MOORS", "#12 DOGWOOD HOLLOW", "#12 MAINSTAY", "#120 THE MOORS", "#13 DOGWOOD HOLLOW", "#13 MEGHAN COVES", "#14 BEACON HILL", "#14 GRAND JEST", "#14 GRAND JEST"), sold = structure(c(13521, 11373, 13413, 14372, 15044, 14056, 15044, 12712, 12671, 12524, 11071, 11856, 11670, 11754, 12251, 11829, 11465, 12600, 11271, 11624, 11831, 11276, 12724, 14040, 11100, 12678, 12174, 12293, 14546, 11430), class = "Date")), .Names = c("address", "sold"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 30L))
df
```

For example, if

```
address       date
123 Main St   2002-03-01 
123 Main St   2005-01-01
```

I just want the 2005 dated line for 123 Main St in the new data frame.

I tried some functions from `dplyr`

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

> df %>% group_by(address) %>% max(df$sold)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
> df %>% group_by(address) %>% max(as.numeric(.(sold)))
Error in function_list[[k]](value) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

> ddply(df, .(address), max(.(sold)))
Error in max(.(sold)) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

I don't know what to do from here and would appreciate help to come up with a way to select for a new data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `arrange` the 'sold' column in descending order and select the first observation with `slice` after grouping by 'address'.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(address)  %>% 
    arrange(desc(sold)) %>%
    slice(1)
```

---

Or get the index of the maximum value of 'sold' (`which.sold`) and use `slice` to get that row after we group by 'address'

```
df %>%
   group_by(address)  %>%
   slice(which.max(sold))
```

---

Or another option is using `top_n`.

```
df %>%
   group_by(address) %>% 
   top_n(1)
```

---

Or if we are using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), order the 'sold' in descending, and use `unique` with the `by` option to select the first observation for each 'address'.

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df)[order(-sold)], by = 'address')
```

Comment: I appreciate your thorough list of options. This is great.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option with dplyr:

```
arrange(df, desc(sold)) %>% distinct(address)
```

This doesn't require a `group_by` operation. We order the data by descending `sold` and then return only the first row per address in case of multiple same entries.

Comment: Your answer is how I would have pictured the solution. Thanks.